# Enviar o conteúdo de uma função do front-end via POST para o node

Tags: node.js, express.js

Olá, gostaria de saber como posso fazer para enviar uma variável dentro de uma função via o método POST do front-end para o back-end, e receber o valor na rota POST do Express?

No frond-end

```
function valor() {
    let valor = 10;
    //ENVIAR O VALOR UTILIZANDO POST
}
```

No back-end com o modulo Express

```
app.post('/valor', function(req, res) {
    //RECEBER O VALOR AQUI
});
```

Comment: *Back-end*: `req.body.field_name` ou instale o(s) módulo(s) *body-parser* e/ou *multer* (para envio de arquivos). *Front-end*: Utilize o `fetch` ou `XMLHttpRequest`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Luis abaixo há um exemplo completo onde um formulário com um único campo é postado em uma determinada rota:

Arquivo `server.js`:

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, '/'));

var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded());

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('myView', { msg: '' } );
});

app.post('/', (req, res) => {
    console.log('Valor postado', req.body.campo1);
    res.render('myView', { msg: 'Dados Processados' } );
});

app.listen(3000, () => console.log(`App listening on port!`));
```

Arquivo `myView.ejs`:

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="text" value="teste" name="campo1" />
    <input type="submit" value="enviar" />
</form>
```

Acredito que estes links podem te ajudar:

- [documentação do Express](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html) e também neste post.
- [Como converter os dados de uma requisição com o body-parser](https://medium.com/@febatista107/como-converter-os-dados-de-uma-requisi%C3%A7%C3%A3o-com-o-body-parser-2b5b93100f00)